integer promotion isn't taken into account
Let's take the following code which we compile for a 32 bit system:
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned char uint8;
...
uint8 y = 0xFF;
uint32 x = (y << 24U);

y can be promoted to int as, and I quote from the C Standard:

If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int

The shifting value is valid as, according to the same standard:

The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

So because y is promoted to an int and the shift value is less than the width of the int (24 < 32), there is no undefined behaviour.
However, Misra has a rule, 12.2, where it states that:

The right hand operand of a shift operator shall lie in the range zero to one less than the width in bits of the essential type of the left hand operand

Note the essential keyword in the rule text. This means that Misra only looks at the essential type of y, which is uint8 and then sees that 24>=8 (width of uint8) thus it treats it as a violation.
Why this discrepancy? If the C compiler allows promotion to be taken into consideration, why isn't Misra? Any C compiler performs the promotion of the left operand thus there can't be a compiler that messes up the shifting due an undefined behaviour.

y << 24U is actually undefined behavior, due to signed overflow.

@Sterpu, try uint32 x = (y << 24U); --> uint32 x = y; y <<= 24U;

@chux: You meant x, not y, for x << = 24U; (or 24; for shift operators, the type of the right operand is independent of the left operand, and there is no reason to prefer unsigned int).

@EricPostpischil Yes, meant y <<= 24u;.  True that 24u and 24 should both work without complaint.  Sadly I've come across MISRA that complains about 24, yet accepts 24u and so wanted to first advise 24u, then if that works for OP, later 24.

The MISRA rule is intended to protect against variations in platform integer size. On a typical system with 32-bit ints, it's possible to shift a small enough unsigned char left 24 bits without overflow (though your particular example still exhibits signed overflow). But such platforms are not the only platforms MISRA C is concerned with.
Some platforms have 16-bit ints. On a platform with 16-bit int and 8-bit char, trying to shift an unsigned char left 24 bits would automatically be undefined behavior.
It would be possible for MISRA to specify a more lenient rule that still protects against platform variation, by accounting for the standard-mandated minimum width of an int, which is at least 16 bits. But the goal of MISRA C is better served by choosing consistency over leniency.
Your particular example is undefined behavior even with 32-bit ints. y gets promoted to a signed int, not unsigned, and the value of y is big enough that the shift produces signed overflow.

Could you please also explain why the unsigned char is promoted to an int and not to an unsigned int? What would be the rationale?

@SterpuMihai: That's how C integer promotion works. It's even in the standard quote in your question. It's a very error-prone rule, but that's the rule.

If you read the spec carefully it states "If E1 has a signed type", not "If E1 has a signed promoted type". This is a bit fuzzy as the same specs insist on using the "promoted" keyword a paragraph above

@SterpuMihai: Arguably, you could read that line as referring to the unpromoted type. But if you try to actually apply the "If E1 has an unsigned type" rule here, the value you get doesn't fit in the (signed) result type, so you've still got signed overflow.

Ok. One more. Let's now make y = 3. I agree the C standard states that y is now promoted to int and 3 x 2^24 fits into an int (50331648 < 2147483647). So this wouldn't be undefined behaviour, right? And Misra would still consider it violates rule 12.2 as it still considers the 8 bits y is represented on, not the promotion.

@SterpuMihai: Yes.

@SterpuMihai The arithmetic/logical operators are specified to produce a mathematical result which is then converted to the result type (possibly inducing UB). For example, the + operator is specified to produce the sum of its operands, but when converted to the result type it might not be the actual sum any more (inducing UB if the result type is a signed integer type, but not if it is an unsigned integer type).

@IanAbbott: Saying they produce a result that is converted to the result type is not a good way of phrasing it, because an out-of-range conversion is implementation-defined, not undefined. The operators are specified to produce a mathematical result in the result type, and, if that is not possible, an exceptional condition occurs. C 2024 6.5.1: “… If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined…”

@EricPostpischil I think I was using the word "conversion" a bit loosely, but that's more or less what I was trying to convey. Some mathematical result is notionally produced that may or may not be representable by the result type.

C17 6.5.7p4:

If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is
representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The result type is int, which (assuming typical 32 bit types) cannot represent 255 × 2^24 = 4278190080 as it is greater than 2^31-1 = 2147483647. Thus the behavior is undefined.

In my example, E1 is y which has an unsigned type.

@SterpuMihai: You acknowledge in the question that y is promoted to an int. So the promoted left operand of << is signed, and the shift overflows.


y can be promoted to int as, and I quote from the C standard

That is correct, it is promoted to an int as per integer promotion before shift (see Implicit type promotion rules). MISRA C also explains this briefly in the introductory part of chapter 10 of MISRA C:2023.
What might be the root of your confusion is the peculiar part with shift operators specifically. They do not apply the "usual arithmetic conversions" like most binary operators. For example in case of y + 24U then y would be balanced to unsigned int before addition. But in case of shift, "the type of the result is that of the promoted left operand" as said in the part you quote. Therefore the type of the right operand is irrelevant.

The shifting value is valid as, according to the same standard

No. See C23 6.5.8, emphasis mine:

The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. /--/

(Now the left operand is int in your case.)

The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2, wrapped around. If E1 has a signed type and
nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value;
otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Specifically 0xFF * 2^24 = 4,278,190,080. The range of int only goes up to 2^31-1 = 2,147,483,647.

Note the essential keyword in the rule text. This means that Misra only looks at the essential type of y, which is uint8 and then sees that 24>=8(width of uint8) thus it treats it as a violation.

Yes and that's a sound rule since it prevents undefined behavior in this case.
General best practice: When the left operand of a shift is a small integer type, then before shifting always cast the left operand to either unsigned int or the equivalent stdint.h type (either uint16_t or uint32_t depending on system).
